# Default Values don't work with Positional and Optional arguments present

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

My code (train.py):

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    parser.add_argument('data_dir')
    parser.add_argument('--save_dir', type = str, default = 'save_directory', help = 'Save checkpoint directory')
    parser.add_argument('--arch', type = str, default = 'VGG', help = 'Select architecture. Choose VGG or AlexNet')
    parser.add_argument('--learning_rate', type = float, default = '0.001', help = 'Select the model learning rate')
    parser.add_argument('--hidden_units', type = int, default = '1024', help = 'Select the model hidden units')
    parser.add_argument('--epochs', type = int, default = '2', help = 'Select the number of epochs')
    parser.add_argument('--gpu', type = str, default = 'gpu', help = 'Select the device type. CPU or GPU.')

    return parser.parse_args()
```

When I try to run

> python train.py data_dir --arch

I get

> train.py: error: argument --arch: expected one argument

Why do my default values not work?

Comment: The default kicks in if you omit `--arch` entirely. How do you want this to work? If you omit `--arch`, it's `None`, if you supply `--arch` it's `VGG`, if you supply `--arch foo`, it's `foo`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default values are substituted when the corresponding argument is *not present*.

You have defined `--arch` as "an optional argument which takes string values, and if not present it should be `VGG`"

If you pass `--arch` it should have a string value. If you don't pass `--arch` it will be `VGG`.

You have tried something in-between. That's an error case.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand. My code has no error, its just that I didnt properly understand how the optional arguments work.

Answer (score 2):

There are three ways you can pass the `'--arch'` argument:

1. Not at all, which will use the value from `default`.
2. With `'--arch'` alone, which will use the value from `const`. Since `const` was originally not specified, this case defaulted to `None`, making it the same as the first case.
3. With `'--arch <value>'`, which will use `<value>`.

Therefore, you need to specify that the flag takes a further optional argument with `nargs='?'`, and the value of `const`:

```
parser.add_argument('--arch',
                    nargs='?', 
                    type=str, 
                    const='VGG',
                    default='VGG',
                    help='Select architecture. Choose VGG or AlexNet')
```

You may also wish to note that you can pass `choices=['VGG', 'AlexNet']` to constrain the available choices (an error will be raised if the argument is not in `choices`).

Comment: Even with `nargs='?` the default is still not used and instead gives me `NoneType` back. The answer above made me understand I was thinking about this the wrong way.

Comment: @ConstantinosN I have edited my answer (I originally mixed up `default` with `const`). See the edit for a more detailed explanation of why your code didn't work and why `nargs='?'` was correct, just incomplete.